# RecycleView list items not appearing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, anko

I've been trying to make `RecyclerView` work in my app where the list items are `ImageView`s, and the images get downloaded and put inside (asynchronously) in the `onBindViewHolder` method. I'm not facing any errors in my code, but for some reason

> only the list items which will be visible (even partially) to the user
>   when the activity loads, have images loaded into them.

Though I can't see the images, I observed that the height and width of these items have been allocated correctly. And since the images get downloaded first, and then the `ImageView`'s dimensions are determined I figure that the problem has got something to do with `RecyclerView` itself? If someone can shed some light on this, it would be great. Thanks.

I would also like to add, that if the Activity is paused and then resumed (by clicking on the "square" navigation button and then resuming it), the images of all the list items load correctly.

Pic #1
[image: as you can see the gray portion where an image is supposed to be]
Pic #2
[image: somewhat more convincing :)]

Here's my code:

`onCreate` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView {
            id = ViewID.ID_LIST
        }

        val imgList = ArrayList<ImageView>()
        imgList.add(ImageView(ctx))
        imgList.add(ImageView(ctx))
        imgList.add(ImageView(ctx))
        imgList.add(ImageView(ctx))
        val lv = findViewById(ViewID.ID_LIST) as RecyclerView
        lv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        lv.adapter = ImageRecyclerAdapter(ctx, imgList)

}
```

The `RecyclerView.Adapter` class:

```
private class ImageRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, val imageList: ArrayList<ImageView>) :
            RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder)
            if (holder != null) {
                val v = holder.itemView as ImageView
                v.setImageBitmap(null)
            }
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val v = p.itemView as ImageView
            Ion.with(v)
                    .load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616076655547682816/6gMRtQyY.jpg")
                    .setCallback({ exception, t ->
                        if (t != null) {
                            val dm = Point()
                            context.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(dm)
                            val w = t.maxWidth
                            val h = t.maxHeight

                            val params = t.layoutParams
                            if (params != null) {
                                params.width = dm.x
                                params.height = (dm.x * (h.toDouble() / w.toDouble())).toInt()
                                t.layoutParams = params
                                t.requestLayout()
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return imageList.size
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val v = ImageView(context)
            return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: you know what? that is complete misunderstanding of logic behind recyclerView, adapter and ViewHolder. Adapter should bind data to views, but you are trying to put views to views. RTFM https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: how is images not being set when it is invisible to the user a problem? Actually that is why recyclerviews are used..check https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html . If you still dont need it then you should just use listview

Comment: @SurajRao The images are not being set even when it is visible to the user. For example, see the screenshot.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I am not sure I understand where lies my mistake, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Read the manual, it has example. Adapter is the pattern when you map two incompatible classes one with other, so you should map your data to the view in bindView method of adapter. It seems that your data is the URL of image, so you should provide arrayList of urls to adapter and in adapter in bindView you should load image from url to the imageView which will be in your ViewHolder

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I was just testing how `RecyclerView` works using that, and was going to adopt what you said in my actual project.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I made the binding of data into a **Synchronous** request, and I moved the `ImageView` manipulation (changing `LayoutParams`) into the `onViewAttachedToWindow` overridden method of my adapter.

`onViewAttachedToWindow`:

```
override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    val t = holder?.itemView as ImageView
    val dm = Point()
    context.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(dm)
    val w = t.maxWidth
    val h = t.maxHeight
    val params = t.layoutParams
    if (params != null) {
        params.width = dm.x
        params.height = (dm.x * (h.toDouble() / w.toDouble())).toInt()
        t.layoutParams = params
        t.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

`onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val v = p.itemView as ImageView
    Ion.with(v)
            .load(imageList[position].toString())
            .tryGet()
}
```